# problem with java task in Apache Ant

Tags: java, apache, ant

I am an Apache Ant novice and I would like to create a build file with a run task. The run task should execute the following command line statemenet

```
java -classpath C:/tmp/SYS/doodle.jar;C:/tmp/SYS/CTX.jar sys.ctx.doodle.Start
```

where the sys.ctx.doodle.Start class is located in the doodle.jar

My question is: how can I add two elements in a classpath? 
I have tried the following:

```
<target name="run">
   <java jar="C:/tmp/SYS/doodle.jar" fork="true">
  <classpath>
      <pathelement location="C:/tmp/SYS/doodle.jar"/>
      <pathelement path="sys.ctx.doodle.Start"/>
  </classpath>
  <classpath>   
       <pathelement location="C:/tmp/SYS/CTX.jar"/>
  </classpath>
   </java>
</target>
```

But when executing it throws me a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Any idea where the problem may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transpose your command-line path into the Ant [`java` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) classpath attribute directly.  Ant should take care of recognising that is composed of semicolon-delimited jar names.

```
<java classpath="C:/tmp/SYS/doodle.jar;C:/tmp/SYS/CTX.jar" ... >
```

Or you can specify it as a nested element as you currently have:

```
<java ... >
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="C:/tmp/SYS/doodle.jar;C:/tmp/SYS/CTX.jar" />
    </classpath>
</java>
```

The argument `sys.ctx.doodle.Start` looks like the name of the class you want to run. Use the `classname` attribute to pass that to the `java` task.  Putting that with the classpath leads to:

```
<java classpath="C:/tmp/SYS/doodle.jar;C:/tmp/SYS/CTX.jar"
      classname="sys.ctx.doodle.Start" />
```

The `jar` attribute should be used only when you want to run the `Main-Class` included in that jar.

Answer (score 2):

For adding multiple jars to your classpath reference using a [Fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)seems to be a clean way to do it

example:

```
<classpath>
  <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
  <fileset dir="lib">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</classpath>
```

Will add all jars inside the lib directory to the classpath.

Comment: Anto This might be better approach. Add libs needed to be in classpath into lib directory and then put above code into build.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `<classpath>` elements. What you need is single `<classpath>` element like this:

```
<classpath>
      <pathelement location="C:/tmp/SYS/doodle.jar"/>
       <pathelement location="C:/tmp/SYS/CTX.jar"/>
  </classpath>
```

You will need to change the `<java>` tag like this:

```
<java jar="C:/tmp/SYS/doodle.jar" fork="true" classname="sys.ctx.doodle.Start">
```